# CASESAFEID() apex equivalent

Tags: apex, formula

Is there any function in Apex which could emulate functionality of the **[CASESAFEID()](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CASESAFEID)** formula function? I'm trying to get 18-char Id variant from the standard one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Per the [Apex docs on primitive datatypes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm), "Note that if you set [an] ID to a 15-character value, Apex automatically converts the value to its 18-character representation."  So it should be enough to assign your 15 character id to an ID-typed variable, and then back to a string, like so:

```
string idStr = '001E000000nwg7g';   // 15 character id
id idval = idStr;                   // assign to ID variable
idStr = idval;                      // back to string to prove the point
system.debug('18 char: ' + idStr);  // note that you could just append idval instead
                                    // of converting to string first
```

Remember that assigning an invalid id string to an ID-typed variable will throw an exception; if there's any chance that your 15 character value may not be a valid id, wrap the assignment in a try/catch block.

Comment: Good enough for me :)
Thank you, Jason!

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down line by line for understanding. Assuming you start with `accountId` as a 15 char string, one could get this done in one line: `accountId = (String)(Id)accountId`.

Comment: @SwisherSweet in fact, you can just use `accountId = (Id)accountId;`, as Id values are always implicitly cast to 18-character strings whenever they are used as strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can just type the string cast to ID. Like (Id) idStr;