# Fetching AccountTeamMember using id from loookup on account

Tags: apex, visualforce

this is the structure of my code:

In the constructor i build a fake account which i use into a visualforce page to get an inputfield which can lookup into accounts through the OwnerId.

```
userInput = new Account();
```

Then i have a method which tries to fetch account teams using the OwnerId previously set.

```
String rolestring = 'Core User';

AccountTeamMember[] clients = [Select UserId, AccountId, TeamMemberRole From AccountTeamMember Where UserId = :userInput.OwnerId AND TeamMemberRole = :rolestring];
```

This simply isn't working.
I tried the very same query through the developer console (and it works fine) but even by putting a fixed 15-digits ID for the userId, it's not working.
Then i tried with the same ID but with its 18-digit version and it WORKS.
So the question is: how can i get the 18-digit version of the id i previously put in the OwnerId field of my 'fake' account?
I also tried to fetch the user and assign its ID to an ID variable but it's still not working ! (i found [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/casesafeid-apex-equivalent) saying it would do the trick but it doesn't !)
I am basically looking for something like the CASESAFEID function but for Apex!

Comment: The answer you linked *is* the correct method. There's something else wrong in your code.

Comment: I guess the ownerId for you is null .Put debug logs and figure whats wrong

Comment: OwnerId is not null, i tried to fetch the user using that id and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for partner users and i had another user with the same name of the one i was testing with.
It seems no partner users can be shown in the inputfield lookups.